# Wordpress - Changed login URL but still getting hacked

Tags: wordpress, authentication

I have a Wordpress site that has very recently getting a lot of login attempts.  Woke up with over 100 alerts, and they are still coming in.  I changed the login url to something obscure, but I am still getting alerts of users trying to login, they are using different usernames each time.  And different IP addresses.  I have never had this number of attempts on any of my Wordpress websites.  Any ideas how I can stop them from even being able to try and login?  I thought hiding the login url would have worked.

Comment: Check this post http://creativewebbiz.com/2013/01/17/protect-wordpress-from-hackers/

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I have already taken these steps.  I do this for all my websites.  How are the hackers able to even try and login to my site if I changed the login url to an obscure url?

Comment: Login url is easily to detect. As you can always access wp-login.php page. Instead of changing wp-admin folder name.

Comment: I have changed the url to the login page though?